# Change custom loss parameter and NN parameter with respect to epoch

Tags: keras, parameters, loss-function

I have a Keras model defined in the following manner (Tried to keep only the necessary parts):

```
temperature = 5.0

def knowledge_distillation_loss(y_true, y_pred, lambda_const):    
    y_true, logits = y_true[:, :10], y_true[:, 10:]
    y_soft = K.softmax(logits/temperature)
    y_pred, y_pred_soft = y_pred[:, :10], y_pred[:, 10:]    

    return lambda_const*logloss(y_true, y_pred) + logloss(y_soft, y_pred_soft)

def get_model(num_labels):
    #Some layers for model
    model.add(Dense(num_labels))
    logits = model.layers[-1].output
    probabilities = Activation('softmax')(logits)
    # softed probabilities
    logits_T = Lambda(lambda x: x/temperature)(logits)
    probabilities_T = Activation('softmax')(logits_T)

    output = concatenate([probabilities, probabilities_T])
    model = Model(model.input, output)

    lambda_const = 0.07

    model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-1, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True), 
    loss=lambda y_true, y_pred: knowledge_distillation_loss(y_true, y_pred, lambda_const), 
    metrics=[accuracy])
    return model
```

I am following [this reference](https://github.com/TropComplique/knowledge-distillation-keras/blob/master/knowledge_distillation_for_mobilenet.ipynb).

This is implemented using `fit generator()` on Keras with tf backend. Obviously, I will have trouble when loading the model since `temperature` is hared coded. 
Also, 
I wish to update `temperature` parameter with respect to the epoch number in both loss function and model.

How do I define such a control signal?

Comment: So, do you need a new answer?

Comment: No, I just wanted to give matt a bounty for his help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've turned this into a complete example of one way to do this.

You could make a class for the loss function.

```
class TemperatureLossFunction:
    def __init__(self, temperature):
        self.temperature = temperature
    def loss_fun(self, y_truth, y_pred):
        return self.temperature*keras.losses.mse(y_truth, y_pred)
    def setTemperature(self, t, session=None):
        if session:
            session.run(self.temperature.assign( t )
        elif tensorflow.get_default_session():
            tensorflow.get_default_session().run(self.temperature.assign( t ))

class TemperatureLossCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, temp_lf):
        self.temp_lf = temp_lf
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, params):
        self.temp_lf.setTemperature(epoch)
```

I've created two methods for working with this, the first method creates and saves the model.

```
def init(session):
    global temperature #global for serialization issues
    temperature = tensorflow.Variable(5.0)
    tlo = TemperatureLossFunction(temperature)

    inp = keras.layers.Input((4,4))

    l1 = keras.layers.Lambda( lambda x: temperature*x )
    op = l1(inp)

    m = keras.models.Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[op])
    m.compile( optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(0.01), loss=tlo.loss_fun)

    #make sure the session is the one your using!
    session.run(temperature.initializer)
```

The first test I run makes sure we are changing the value.

```
    m.evaluate( numpy.ones((1, 4, 4)), numpy.zeros((1, 4, 4)) )    
    session.run(temperature.assign(1))
    m.evaluate( numpy.ones((1, 4, 4)), numpy.zeros((1, 4, 4)) )
```

The second test I run makes sure we can change the values with a callback.

```
    cb = TemperatureLossCallback(tlo)
    def gen():
        for i in range(10):
            yield numpy.ones((1, 4, 4)), numpy.zeros((1, 4, 4))
    m.fit_generator(
            gen(), steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=10, callbacks=[cb]
        )
    m.save("junk.h5")
```

Finally, to demonstrate reloading the file.

```
def restart(session):
    global temperature
    temperature = tensorflow.Variable(5.0)
    tlo = TemperatureLossFunction(temperature)
    loss_fun = tlo.loss_fun
    m = keras.models.load_model(
            "junk.h5", 
            custom_objects = {"loss_fun":tlo.loss_fun}
    )
    session.run(temperature.initializer)
    m.evaluate( numpy.ones((1, 4, 4)), numpy.zeros((1, 4, 4)) )
    session.run(temperature.assign(1))
    m.evaluate( numpy.ones( (1, 4, 4) ), numpy.zeros( ( 1, 4, 4) ) )
```

This is just the code I use to start the program for completeness

```
import sys    
if __name__=="__main__":
    sess = tensorflow.Session()
    with sess.as_default():
        if "restart" in sys.argv:
            restart(sess)
        else:
            init(sess)
```

One downside of this method, if you run this you will see that the temperature variable does not get loaded from the model file. It takes on the value assigned in the code.

On the plus side, both the loss function and the layer are referencing the same `Variable`

One way I found to save the variable value is to create a new layer and use the variable as the weight for the new layer.

```
class VLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.v1 = self.add_weight(
                       dtype="float32", 
                       shape = (), 
                       trainable=False, 
                       initializer="zeros"
                   )
    def call(self, x):
        return x*self.v1
    def setValue(self, val):
        self.set_weights( numpy.array([val]) )
```

Now when you load the model, the weight will be loaded. Unfortunately, I could not find a way to link the weight to a Variable on load. So there will be two variables, one for the loss function and one for the layer. Both of them can be set from a callback though. So I feel this method is on a more robust path.

Comment: It does matter to me. I wish to load the model later and use it to predict. Will that cause me any trouble?

Comment: @havakok when you load the model w/out compile it will be fine. What that means is if you start training, then try to restart training, there will be some differences. For making predictions it is fine, since a prediction doesn't use the training/optimizer values, it just uses the trained weights.